# Installing Charles certificate on TvOS 10.2.2

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, tvos, charles-proxy, apple-configurator

I'm having trouble installing an Apple Configurator profile (which includes the Charles certificate) on TvOS (version 10.2.2). I am running Sierra version 10.12.6 alongside Apple Configurator 2.4. TvOS recognises the profile I wish to install and on the install profile screen I see "not signed". 
[Install profile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcHUW.jpg)

I click on "done" to add the profile but have no idea where I find the URL of the profile I wish to add. 
[Add profile URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruamj.jpg)

Has anyone else had success with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Apple Configurator 2 App on a Mac to install the profile. You can download that app from the Apple developer site. Once you get the device added to Apple Configurator, you can add/edit profiles.

[image: Screenshot of Apple Configurator 2]